# How use CALayer to draw an image in an NSCollectionViewItem

Tags: swift, macos, calayer, nsimage, nscollectionview

To resolve performance issues with a big collection view, I am trying to replace NSImageView's using CALayer() to draw images inside NSCollectionViewItem.

The code works when used with a simple NSView, but I am not able to get it work on an NSCollectionViewItem; the image is not drawn, only the background color.

```
func collectionView( _ collectionView: NSCollectionView, willDisplay item: NSCollectionViewItem, forRepresentedObjectAt indexPath: IndexPath )
{
    guard let image = NSImage( byReferencingFile: "test.jpg" ) else
    {
        return
    }

    let imageLayer = CALayer()

    item.view.wantsLayer = true
    item.view.layer?.addSublayer( imageLayer )

    imageLayer.frame            = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100 , height: 100 )
    imageLayer.contents         = image
    imageLayer.masksToBounds    = true
    imageLayer.autoresizingMask = [ .layerHeightSizable, .layerWidthSizable ];
    imageLayer.contentsGravity  = CALayerContentsGravity.resizeAspect;
    imageLayer.backgroundColor  = CGColor(red: 67/255, green: 173/255, blue: 247/255, alpha: 1.0)

    imageLayer.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

I have tried to move the code by subclassing NSCollectionViewItem but get the same result.

What am I missing with the layers in NSCollectionViewItem?

**Edit:**

It seems that the problem is with `.setNeedsDisplay()`. Removing this line works...

Comment: Try moving the `addSublayer` call to just before `setNeedsDisplay()`

Comment: @Koen already tried, same result.

Comment: Do you know if this method is called at all (is the delegate set up)? Did you try moving the code to `itemForRepresentedObjectAt` ?

Comment: Yes the method is called. Same result if I move the code to `itemForRepresentedObjectAt`. Adding a background color or even a CATextLayer() works fine, the problem is just with images.